# sox returns an error when I try to handle mp3 files

Tags: mp3, sox

Hello so here is the deal, I used:

```
$ yum install sox
```

To install it in CentOS 6. After that I did a quick test:

```
$ sox test.mp3 test.amr
```

and this is what it returns:

```
$ sox formats: no handler for file extension `mp3'
```

I need this done with `sox` not `lame` because I will need to use it for mixing and other functions not available with `lame`.

Comment: In a Cygwin environment, install packages `sox-fmt-ao` and `sox-fmt-pulseaudio`.

Answer (score 4):

The vanilla version of `sox` on CentOS doesn't support the `mp3` codec. Here's a list of what it does support.

```
$ sox
...
AUDIO FILE FORMATS: 8svx aif aifc aiff aiffc al amb au avr caf cdda cdr cvs cvsd
cvu dat dvms f32 f4 f64 f8 fap flac fssd gsm gsrt hcom htk ima ircam la lpc 
lpc10 lu mat mat4 mat5 maud nist ogg paf prc pvf raw s1 s16 s2 s24 s3 s32 s4 s8 
sb sd2 sds sf sl smp snd sndfile sndr sndt sou sox sph sw txw u1 u16 u2 u24 u3 
u32 u4 u8 ub ul uw vms voc vorbis vox w64 wav wavpcm wv wve xa xi
PLAYLIST FORMATS: m3u pls
AUDIO DEVICE DRIVERS: alsa ao oss ossdsp pulseaudio
```

You can download the source RPM of `sox` and recompile with `libmad` and `lame-devel` libraries installed to add support for this feature.

This tutorial should help, titled: [INSTALLING SOX W/ MP3 SUPPORT ON CENTOS 5.X](http://techblog.netwater.com/?p=4), though it's for CentOS 5.x it should still apply. There are also steps in the comments of that post for compiling `sox` with `mp3` support on CentOS 6.x.

#### Steps

From the comments.

*The one-stop solution for CentOS 6.4 without mad or libid3tag (YMMV):*

```
### as root

$ yum install -y sox lame    
$ mkdir /usr/local/src/SoX
$ cd /usr/local/src/SoX
$ wget http://downloads.sourceforge.net/project/sox/sox/14.4.1/sox-14.4.1.tar.gz?r=http%3A%2F%2Fsourceforge.net%2Fprojects%2Fsox%2Ffiles%2Fsox%2F14.4.1%2F&ts=1366019279&use_mirror=freefr
$ tar -xvzf sox-14.4.1.tar.gz
$ cd sox-14.4.1/
$ ./configure
$ make -s
$ make install
$ echo “include /usr/local/lib” >> /etc/ld.so.conf
$ /sbin/ldconfig
```

#### Repo #1 - RPM Fusion

To be able to install `lame` you'll need to add an additional YUM Repo to your mix. The repo that contains `lame` is called [RPM Fusion](http://rpmfusion.org/). At the time that I'm writing this the latest version of the RPM that will install the RPM Fusion repo is at: [rpmfusion-nonfree-release-6-1.noarch](http://download1.rpmfusion.org/nonfree/el/updates/6/x86_64/rpmfusion-nonfree-release-6-1.noarch.rpm). To install it:

```
$ sudo rpm -ivh http://download1.rpmfusion.org/nonfree/el/updates/6/x86_64/rpmfusion-nonfree-release-6-1.noarch.rpm
```

**NOTE:** You may need an [RPM signing keys](http://rpmfusion.org/keys), specifically [this one for EL6](http://rpmfusion.org/keys?action=AttachFile&do=view&target=RPM-GPG-KEY-rpmfusion-nonfree-el-6).

#### Repo #2 - EPEL

Installing the RPM Fusion repo requires another YUM repo called [EPEL - Extra Packages for Enterprise Linux](http://fedoraproject.org/wiki/EPEL). You'll need to install this RPM as well, priror to installing RPM Fusion's RPM.

```
$ sudo rpm -ivh http://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/6/x86_64/epel-release-6-8.noarch.rpm
```

**NOTE:** The version number on this repo changes from time to time so it's best to check what the lastest one is. Currently at the time of this post the latest version was 6.8. You can see these numbers in the package name above, "epel-release-6-8.noarch.rpm".

#### References

- [How do I convert a wav file to mp3 format using sox?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1043370/how-do-i-convert-a-wav-file-to-mp3-format-using-sox)

Comment: when I do yum install lame, it returns package not found.it says sox installed.but no lame package lame available.

Comment: @fogsy - have you ever recompiled a RPM package before?

Comment: yes I did recompile sox actually just today

Comment: Using a source RPM or did you just download the tar.gz file for the sox package and compile that? I'd try the updates I added, if you're stuck or that approach doesn't work, I noticed in the RPM Fusion repo a package that appears to be an MP3 enabled version of sox: [sox-plugins-nonfree](http://download1.rpmfusion.org/nonfree/fedora/releases/18/Everything/source/SRPMS/repoview/sox-plugins-nonfree.html). This is a source RPM for Fedora but can be rebuilt for CentOS 6.

Comment: tar gz the same way you wrote on your answer - thanks for your help btw. this is what adding the new yum repo returned : warning: /var/tmp/rpm-tmp.jWYeuB: Header V3 RSA/SHA256 Signature, key ID 5568bbb2: NOKEY
error: Failed dependencies:
        epel-release >= 6 is needed by rpmfusion-nonfree-release-6-1.noarch
        rpmfusion-free-release >= 6 is needed by rpmfusion-nonfree-release-6-1.noarch

Comment: @fogsy - see updates, you need EPEL, I added that repo too. Should be the last of it.

Comment: @fogsy - you're welcome, glad to assist, and thanks for the Q. Please make sure to mark it as accepted so others know you're issue's been resolved.

Answer (score 3):

It can be solved esaily with

```
yum install sox soxr sox-plugins-freeworld -y
```

sox-plugins-freeworld include mp3 support.

Comment: Thanks! On Debian, it's `libsox-fmt-mp3`

Answer (score 0):

You need to add support for the `mp3` codec, in Ubuntu this is provided by the package: `libsox-fmt-mp3`

```
sudo apt show libsox-fmt-mp3

Package: libsox-fmt-mp3
Version: 14.4.2+git20190427-2+deb11u2ubuntu0.20.04.1
Priority: optional
Section: universe/sound
Source: sox
Origin: Ubuntu
Maintainer: Ubuntu Developers <ubuntu-devel-discuss@lists.ubuntu.com>
Original-Maintainer: Debian Multimedia Maintainers <debian-multimedia@lists.debian.org>
Bugs: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+filebug
Installed-Size: 80,9 kB
Depends: libc6 (>= 2.14), libid3tag0 (>= 0.15.1b), libmad0 (>= 0.15.1b-3), libmp3lame0 (>= 3.100), libsox3 (>= 14.4.2~), libtwolame0 (>= 0.3.10)
Homepage: https://sox.sourceforge.io/
Download-Size: 16,0 kB
APT-Manual-Installed: yes
APT-Sources: http://uy.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/universe amd64 Packages
Description: SoX MP2 and MP3 format library
 SoX is the swiss army knife of sound processing.
 .
 This package contains the SoX MP2 and MP3 format library.
 Read support by libmad. MP2 and MP3 write support by libtwolame and
 libmp3lame respectively.
 .
 libmad: https://www.underbit.com/products/mad/
 lame: https://lame.sourceforge.io
```

To install it: `sudo apt install libsox-fmt-mp3`